# Insert Into statement with strings that include , ' " symbols

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert an integer and two text strings one after the other. Each string can include some single & double quotation and commas. It is giving me error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 's'

and the colors in ssms aren't the way its supposed to be but are rather random.

I tried inserting `'` before and after the column name in the after the table name

```
insert into Items_Desc (fK_itemnum, desc_wUOM, desc_woUOM) 
values
(1, 'Careus seat covers 20/250s', 'Careus seat covers'),
(2, 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x90"',10/20s', 'Plastus Table Sheet 66" x 90"'),
(3, 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x72",10/24s', 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x 72"'),
(4, 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x90"',10/16s', 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x 90"'),
(5, 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x72"',10/20s', 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x 72"')
```

Comment: Singles quotes in string literals need to be escaped by doubling them. But I cannot figure out what belongs to what in your statement.

Comment: The syntax highlight colors do not factor in nested quotes (exemplified in your question). What is the error code and message?

Comment: Try doubling every literal apostrophe, ie change `'foo'bar'` to `'foo''bar'`

Comment: @Bohemian Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 's'.

Comment: From [Character String Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "If a character string enclosed in single quotation marks contains an embedded quotation mark, represent the embedded single quotation mark with two single quotation marks. This is not required in strings embedded in double quotation marks."

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
 INSERT INTO items_desc 
                (fk_itemnum, 
                 desc_wuom, 
                 desc_wouom) 
    VALUES      (1, 
                 'Careus seat covers 20/250s', 
                 'Careus seat covers'), 
                (2, 
                 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x90"'',10/20s', 
                 'Plastus Table Sheet 66" x 90"'), 
                (3, 
                 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x72",10/24s''', 
                 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x 72"'), 
                (4, 
                 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x90"'',10/16s', 
                 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x 90"'), 
                (5, 
                 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x72"'',10/20s', 
                 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x 72"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of your insert statement:

```
insert into Items_Desc (fK_itemnum, desc_wUOM, desc_woUOM) 
values
(1, 'Careus seat covers 20/250s', 'Careus seat covers')
,(2, 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x90"'',10/20s', 'Plastus Table Sheet 66" x 90"')
,(3, 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x72",10/24s', 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x 72"')
,(4, 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x90"'',10/16s', 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x 90"')
,(5, 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x72"'',10/20s', 'Plastus Table Sheets 66" x 72"')
```

And the explanation:
In SQL Server, a single quot represents the beginning or end of a string.
In order to pass in a string that contains a single quot, you need to escape it by doubling it - so a string like `Hi, I'm Zohar` should be `Hi, I''m Zohar`.

That being said, the fact that your original strings has adjacent single and double quotes makes it very hard to find the problematic single quotes reading all five rows at once - so the simplest way to fix that is to divide and conquer - which is why I've moved the commas to the beginning of the rows instead of leaving them at the end. That allowed me to simply comment out all rows but the first, run the insert, and repeat until I've found the first problematic row. Fix that row and repeat the process - so in a matter of less than a minute I was able to find and fix all three problematic rows using a test environment.